# Working with JDL in jhipster java change database structure

Tags: java, jhipster, jdl

I try do work on a side project with jhipster. I like the way to change the Database structure  in JDL Studio (Web version). But i have some struggle to work nice with changes.

What i do, i have now my basic Database structure for example Book And Author.
I have made some changes on the models because of @jsonignore and caching and some changes in Angular .ts for example some files that only cleint need/have for the view. And now it looks ok, but i wont to extend my structure.
But by importing this jdl again, i have a lot of work to do, to accept or ignore my own changes. 
Is there a better way to do this? maybe don't change generated files?

jhipster v4.14.4, monolith

Comment: Try re-generating on a git branch and merging with `-s recursive -Xours` options. See https://gist.github.com/gmarziou/6cc0788f8e7cb21a61a7b14f32b9a657  Also if you used @jsongnore and made some changes to API, consider using DTOs.

Comment: that sounded better than it is. because, I still have to check all changes on services and co by hand while importing the jdl

Answer (score 0):

My work steps for jhipster:

- Use generator from your repo (fork).
- Change generator for your general purpose.
- Duplicate UI file for customization to custom directory and change route for menu.
- Use file compare tools (for example beyond compare) for transfer codes to your customized files.